# Get an item value from a column item concatenated

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

How do I achieve a specific result concatenated with commas (ACT1, ACT2) from a filtered text ("Not delivered") and referenced from the position of the columns:

[image: WA103237 example]

Comment: Was one of the answers provided able to do what you required? If so, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the coloured row is Row1, please try in G2 and copied down to suit:

```
=regexreplace(if(C2="Not delivered",C$1&", ","")&if(D2="Not delivered",D$1&", ","")&if(E2="Not delivered",E$1&", ","")&if(F2="Not delivered",F$1&", ",""),",\s\z","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
=iferror(textjoin(", ",,filter(C$1:F$1,C2:F2="Not delivered")),)
```

[IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
[TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Answer (score -1):

The following formula uses the array handling feature of Google Sheets to create a custom array, then TRANSPOSE in order to be able to use QUERY to filter the custom array, then JOIN to concatenate the filtered values.

```
=JOIN(", ",
  QUERY(TRANSPOSE({$C$1:$F$1;C2:F2}),"select Col1 where Col2 = 'Not delivered'")
)
```